# collectionView re-usable cells causing bugs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a collectionView whose cells are of different sizes and have different content. I am using a cell prototype  for these cells, however, when I am adding more than one cell I get weird UI bugs:

This is what it is supposed to look like
[image: Supposed to]
This is what it actually looks like
[image: Fail]

Code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Card *card = [[[usermanager getSelectedUser] getCards] objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    [card setupLayout];

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    [cell addSubview:card];
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    cell.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.bounds] CGPath];

    //Add dropshadow
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 5.0f);
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

    return cell;
}
```

It propably has something to do with the fact that I use the reusable cell. Because when I create 2 different prototypes in my storyboard for these cells they have no problems at all. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: First thing I would try is to create a custom `CardCollectionViewCell` which inherits from `UICollectionViewCell` and implement the `prepareForReuse` method. It is not clear that you have actually re-used any cells from your examples so this might not help, but I suspect you need once a cell gets re-used.

Second thing I am wondering about is what happens if you change the size of the cell to be the same as your card subview.

Thirdly, I am not sure how the default layout handles cells with different sizes. You might need to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and calculate cell positions.

Comment: How do you set the size of your cell? Or you're using dynamic cell size?

Comment: Is it possible to make two subclasses each with a different identifier?

Comment: Is this a retorical question @nacho4d ?

Comment: It is a suggestion. But I am not sure this is possible. That is why I made it a question.

Comment: Ah I see, well, I solved it using the answer below. But thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you say: your cells will be reused, so if you change any layout or frame or colour these properties will be like you set when the cell will be used the next time. you should subclass UICollectionViewCell and implement the method prepareForReuse where you have to reset all views and properties of the cell to the original values and you have to remove the subview card:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    // Reset all, for example backgroundView
    self.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

one more point: why you call `UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];` Thats not correct. You need only `UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: You are propably right, and that last thing was a test for me to see if that changed anything